# Dockerize ASP.NET MVC from a github actions published app output from msbuild

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-mvc-4, github-actions, .net-4.8

I'm dockerizing legacy ASP.NET MVC 4.8, and I had this github actions that build the application.

```
jobs:
  build:
 
    runs-on: windows-latest
 
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      name: Checkout Code
     
    - name: Setup MSBuild Path
      uses: warrenbuckley/Setup-MSBuild@v1
       
    - name: Setup NuGet
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.2
     
    - name: Restore NuGet Packages
      run: nuget restore AspNetMVCApp.sln
 
    - name: Build and Publish Web App
      run: msbuild AspNetMVCApp.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
 
    - name: Upload Artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1.0.0
      with:
        name: aspnet-mvc-app
        path: bin\Release\Publish
```

How do you get the published app and containerize it using something like the below

```
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
# WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
# COPY /src/publish .
```

How do I use that published app and copy it to the `/inetpub/wwwroot`?

Answer (score 0):

Add your Docker image definition to your GitHub repository under the name `Dockerfile` (no extension).

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY /src/publish .
```

Then append your with GitHub Workflow definition with a [`docker/build-push-action@v2`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images) action like below. It'll automatically pickup the `Dockerfile` and use that to build an image. By default it should have access to everything in your repository and all build artifacts.

```
      -
        name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: user/app:latest
```